# iPhone app not working on device

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have iPhone it works fine on simulator but not on device firstly it was working but now it is not working

Also gives below warning

```
WARNING: Using legacy cell layout due to delegate implementation of   tableView:accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath: in <CategoriesList: 0x497b000>.  Please remove your implementation of this method and set the cell properties accessoryType and/or editingAccessoryType to move to the new cell layout behavior.  This method will no longer be called in a future release.
```

this is the first view table view of my app

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];    
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    UIImageView* img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell1.png"]];
    [cell setBackgroundView:img];
    [img release];
}


UIImage *image =  [UIImage   imageNamed:@"arrow.png"] ;
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
button.frame = frame;
[button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonTapped:event:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.accessoryView = button;
Book*aBook=[appDelegate.books objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSString*celltext=aBook.name;
cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
cell.textLabel.text=celltext;
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
self.tableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
self.title=aBook.name;

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
//cell.textLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
//UIImage* theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell1.png"];
//cell.image = theImage;
return cell;
```

}

```
     - (void)checkButtonTapped:(id)sender event:(id)event
    {
 NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
 UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
 CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.tableView];
  NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];
  if (indexPath != nil)
  {   
     [self tableView: self.tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: indexPath];  
        }

 }
```

Comment: Are you implementing this method `- (UITableViewCellAccessoryType)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`  ?

Comment: no i am not implementing this

Answer (score 0):

you have not told us the reason why its not working? are you getting any error or crash
Related to your warning:

> A accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath method identified as deprecated has been superseded and may become unsupported in the future.
>
> **So you need to use the accessory-view and accessory-type properties (for both normal and editing modes) of the UITableViewCell class when configuring table-view cells.**